# ReferenceError: selVal is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

[image]This is the function i'm using for after upload success, when i called this function on success,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                                function upload_submit{{ key }}(id, fileName){
                                    jQuery(".qq-upload-drop-area").hide();
                                    jQuery(".qq-upload-fail").hide();
                                }
                                function upload_success{{ key }}(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                                    var remove_class = 'remove_image_link' 
                                     if ( {{ twd.show_leftbox }} && {{ twd.show_rightbox }} )
                                          remove_class = 'remove_image_link_side' 

                                    var removeLink{{ key }} = "&nbsp;<a class='text-danger' onclick='RemoveImage(\"{{ key }}\",\"{{ pages.page_title }}\")' href='javascript:void(0)'><i class='fa fa-times-circle "+remove_class+"' ></i></a>";
                                    var html_data;
                                    var imgSrc;
                                    var image_path_http;
                                    if(responseJSON.large_image_name != "" && responseJSON.thumb_image_name!= "") {
                                        html_data = htmlDecode(responseJSON.image_html);
                                    }else{
                                        html_data = responseJSON.large_image_name;
                                        image_path_http = responseJSONimage_path_http;
                                    }
                                    jQuery("#showuploadfile{{ key }}").html(html_data + removeLink{{ key }});
                                    jQuery("#showerrorfile{{ key }}").show();
                                    if({{ key }} == 0) {
                                        imgSrc = image_path_http + '&size=' + selVal() + '&orientation=' + getRadioCheckedValue();
                                        document.getElementById("preview{{cnt}}").src = imgSrc;
                                        document.getElementById("showuploadbutton").style.visibility = "visible";
                                    }
                                }
                            </script>
```

i'm getting the below error. will anyone knows why i'm getting this? 
Here i'm using twig and php

```
ReferenceError: selVal is not defined
imgSrc = image_path_http + '&size=' + selVal() + '&orientation=' + getRadioCheck...
```

Also i defined the function already

```
function selVal() {
return document.getElementById('rdo_size').options[document.getElementById('rdo_size'  ).selectedIndex].value;}
```

Comment: `selVal()` is into an external file?

Comment: yes. it is defined in an external file, where i defined the getRadioCheckedValue() in the same line

Comment: Put that js file avobe your current scipt in your html

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi. Already done

Comment: And test now, it must be worked

Comment: Thanks all. Issue was that the filename i included was wrong. :( . Now it worked